# make cake php validation form to contact form

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I want to make a validation form in cakephp my code form is:

view

```
<div class="well">

<?php
echo $this->Form->create(false);
echo $this->Form->input('name', array('label' => 'name '));
echo $this->Form->input('PHONE_NUMBER', array('label' => 'PHONE_NUMBER '));
echo $this->Form->input('EMAIL', array('label' => 'EMAIL '));
echo $this->Form->input('ISSUE', array('label' => 'ISSUE '));
echo $this->Form->input('IP', array('label' => 'IP '));
echo $this->Form->submit('Send.');
?>
```

Controller

```
<?php
class ContactController extends AppController {


public function index() {
    if (empty($_POST) === FALSE) {
        $message = '';
        $message .=$_POST['data']['EMAIL'] .  ' <br/>';
        $message .=$_POST['data']['name'] .  ' <br/>';
        $message .=$_POST['data']['PHONE_NUMBER'] .  ' <br/>';
        $message .=$_POST['data']['ISSUE'] .  ' <br/>';
        $message .=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] .  ' <br/>';
        mail('mohmed@lcegy.com', 'Support From Website ', $message);
        $this->Session->setFlash("Thanks , an email just sent .");
    }

}
```

}

My question is how to implement validation in this form and how to get the IP address of the visitor?

Comment: `my Question how make vadation to this form and how get ip address to this contact vistor` -- your question is not very clear. What exactly do you need help with? Please edit the question and add more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to update your index() function to look something similar to this:  I think it's more of the cakePHP convention.

```
public function index() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $message = '';
        $message = $this->request->data['EMAIL'];
        ...
    }
}
```

For validation, you can add that to your model.  You could do something similar:

```
public $validate = array(
    'EMAIL' => 'email',
    'name' => array(
        'rule' => 'alphaNumeric',
        'required' => true
      )
);
```

For more validation, you can look at the documentation: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html

You can use $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] to get the client's IP Address.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Do Validation From Your Model by setting Rules as follows

```
 public $validate =

   array(
          'Email' => array
      (
        'rule' => 'notempty'

       ),

);
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do it by model as above given answers but you can also do it at view page by simply adding attributes "require" and define proper types like emails, numbers. eg. in your form:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create(false);
echo $this->Form->input('name', array('label' => 'name ', 'required' => true));
echo $this->Form->input('PHONE_NUMBER', array('label' => 'PHONE_NUMBER ', 'required' => true,'type'=>'number'));
echo $this->Form->input('EMAIL', array('label' => 'EMAIL ', 'required' => true, 'type' => 'email'));
echo $this->Form->input('ISSUE', array('label' => 'ISSUE ', 'required' => true));
echo $this->Form->input('IP', array('label' => 'IP ', 'required' => true));
echo $this->Form->submit('Send.');
?>
```